# Access a ng-repeat scope from a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display some comment with two nested ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements" >
   <ul>
      <!-- comments -->
      <li ng-repeat="comment in comments">
         <span>Comment</span> <strong>{{comment.username}}</strong>
         <blockquote>{{comment.content}}</blockquote>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here's what's in the controller:

```
$scope.comments = [];
$scope.populateComments = function(content_id){
   ProjectsService.commentsQuery(content_id)
   .then(function (data) {
      $scope.comments = data;
   })
}
$scope.populateComments(element.id);
```

Obviously it's not working, my problem is that I don't know how, nor if it's possible, to access the property of an object of the ng-repeat scope (to get element.id and get only the comments related to the element involved).
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property of an object of the ng-repeat scope. You need to re-factor your code.

In Html

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements" >
   <ul>
      <!-- comments -->
      <li ng-repeat="comment in element.comments">
         <span>Comment</span> <strong>{{comment.username}}</strong>
         <blockquote>{{comment.content}}</blockquote>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

In JS

```
$scope.populateComments = function(element){
   ProjectsService.commentsQuery(element.id)
   .then(function (data) {
      element.comments = data;
   })
}

$scope.populateComments(element);
```

Comment: Right, my problem is that the ng-repeats are not related to each other, I mean 'comment' is not an instance of the 'element' object, therefore I can't use element.comments to loop! )':